# Inline-block <div> pushed down outside of parent, height more than parent despite height: inherit;

Tags: html, margin, padding, css

## The Problem

1. The `.nav-item` `<div>`s have a greater height than their parent - despite the `height: inherit;`.
2. The `.nav-item` `<div>`s are pushed down outside of their parent, despite the lack of any margins or padding.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <h1>A website</h1>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <p>Item 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <p>Item 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    height: 75px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url('img/gradient.png');
    padding: 0;
}    

#nav h1 {
    top: 8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'Francois One', Impact, Futura, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    display: inline;
}

#nav .nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
}

#nav .nav-item p {
    font-family: 'Francois One', Impact, Futura, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

## Result

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is as expected. The height **will not** be inherited, is calculated by the `text-alignment`, `padding` and `margin` widths. Please do this:

1. Remove `padding` top and bottom.
2. Remove `margin` top and bottom.
3. Add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.nav-item`s.

### Solution

#### CSS

```css
#nav .nav-item {margin: 0; padding: 0 10px; vertical-align: top;}
```

#### Preview:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/vnfdv9bj/

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` and `box-sizing:border-box` to your `.nav-item`:

```css
#nav {
    height: 75px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url('img/gradient.png');
    background:#ff00ff;
    padding: 0;
}    

#nav h1 {
    top: 8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'Francois One', Impact, Futura, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    display: inline;
}

#nav .nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#nav .nav-item p {
    font-family: 'Francois One', Impact, Futura, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <h1>A website</h1>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <p>Item 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <p>Item 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8Lfysh2/)

Answer (score -1):

Or you can simply remove `height:inherit;` too :)

Comment: This does not actually answer the user's question as it does not explain why the unwanted behavior exists. Nor does your solution actually solve the issue.

Comment: He wasn't very clear about the issue, if inherit is removed nav-items stay inside parent div without overflow

Comment: OP was quite clear about the issue. Gave 3 specific undesired behaviors. The accepted answer is correct because it correctly addresses all 3 points... in particular understanding that the height was also being affected by padding and margin. Just something to keep in mind for future answers :)

Comment: I never said that accepted answer is wrong, with my solution( i admit i haven't explain it ) nav-items have normal height and don't overlap his parent, user just said two issues i never talked about accepted solution but thank's for advice

Comment: Providing quality answers is a learned skill. I mention it because even non-accepted answers may have very valuable information for other users who experience similar issues. Consider upgrading the quality of your post rather than simply defending your answer. That's the key to success here on StackOverflow! In fact, often well formed non-accepted answers may provide valuable rep points for you very quickly.

Comment: I understand and consider your point, and i explained you the reason of my answer not just defend it, i explain that it works too from the moment that the issue wasn't clear. In any cases thank's for advice